# Get values from nested forms using final form in react/typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-final-form

I wasn't able to get the values from my nested forms using final form.

here is my **index.tsx**

```
import React, { useState, ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import { Form } from 'react-final-form';
import {
  Box, Typography, Button, IconButton, Grid, FormControl, InputLabel, Select,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import AddCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddCircle';
import FieldInput from 'forms/shared/fields/input';
import FieldFileUploader from 'forms/shared/fields/file-uploader';
import FieldCheckbox from 'forms/shared/fields/checkbox';
import FormRadioQuestions from './partials/form-radio';
import FormExperience from './partials/form-experience';
import FormEducation from './partials/form-education';
import FormPersonalInfo from './partials/form-personal-info';
import FormGovernmentIds from './partials/form-government-id';
import ItemExperience from './partials/experience-item';
import ItemEducation from './partials/education-item';
import useStyles from './styles';

const PublicApplicationForm = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<{ client: string | number; name: string }>({ client: '', name: 'hai' });
  const [showExp, setOpenExp] = useState(false);
  const [showEdu, setOpenEdu] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    experience: [{}],
  });
  const [educations, setEducations] = useState([]);
  const [experiences, setExperiences] = useState([]);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const radioValues = [{ value: 'yes', label: 'Yes' }, { value: 'no', label: 'No' }];
  const variables = { title: 'How did you hear about us?*', typeOfService: 'Type of Service*' };
  const relationOptions = ['Walk-In', 'Employee Referral', 'Job Boards', 'Job Fair', 'Social Media'];
  const checkBoxLabel = 'Please be informed that your application to this job offer will trigger some processing of your personal data by the  company. For more information on data processing, please refer to the company’s talent acquisition privacy policy.';

  const handleChange = ({ target }: ChangeEvent<{ name?: string; value: unknown }>) => {
    setState({ ...state, [target.name as keyof typeof state]: target.value });
  };

  const handleBlur = (event: any) => {
    data.experience[0] = { ...data.experience[0], [event.target.name]: event.target.value };
    setData({ ...data });
  };

  const onAddEdu = (edu: any) => { setEducations([...educations, edu]); setOpenEdu(false); };
  const onAddExp = (exp: any) => { setExperiences([...experiences, exp]); setOpenExp(false); };

  return (
    <Grid className={classes.pageContainer} container>
      <Grid className={classes.formContainer} item xs={12}>
        <Form
          onSubmit={(values) => { console.log(values); }} // eslint-disable-line no-console
          render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <Typography className={classes.formHeading} variant="h5">Personal Information</Typography>
              <Box className={classes.marginedBottom}>
                <FieldFileUploader
                  required
                  fileType="avatars"
                  accept={['image/*']}
                  name="resume"
                />
              </Box>
              <FormPersonalInfo setData={setData} data={data} />
              <Box className={classes.spaced}>
                <Box className={classes.fieldContainer}>
                  <Typography className={classes.noMarginBottom} variant="h6">Experience</Typography>
                  <IconButton color="primary" onClick={() => { setOpenExp(!showExp); }}><AddCircleIcon /></IconButton>
                </Box>
                {
                  showExp && (
                    <FormExperience
                      onCancel={() => setOpenExp(false)}
                      onSave={onAddExp}
                      handleBlur={handleBlur}
                    />
                  )
                }
                {experiences.map((exp, index) => <ItemExperience key={index} exp={exp} />)}
              </Box>
              <Box className={classes.spaced}>
                <Box className={classes.fieldContainer}>
                  <Typography className={classes.noMarginBottom} variant="h6">Education</Typography>
                  <IconButton color="primary" onClick={() => { setOpenEdu(!showEdu); }}><AddCircleIcon /></IconButton>
                </Box>
                {
                  showEdu && (
                    <FormEducation
                      onCancel={() => setOpenEdu(false)}
                      onSave={onAddEdu}
                      setData={setData}
                      data={data}
                    />
                  )
                }
                {educations.map((edu, index) => <ItemEducation key={index} edu={edu} />)}
              </Box>
              <Typography className={classes.formText} variant="h6">On the web</Typography>
              <Box className={classes.fieldContainer}>
                <FieldInput className={classes.textField} type="text" required name="applicant-linkedin" label="Linkedin" onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setData({ ...data, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })} />
              </Box>
              <Box className={`${classes.fieldContainer} ${classes.marginedBottom}`}>
                <FieldInput className={classes.textField} type="text" required name="applicant-facebook" label="Facebook" onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setData({ ...data, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })} />
              </Box>
              <Typography className={classes.formText} variant="h6">Resume</Typography>
              <Box className={`${classes.fieldContainer} ${classes.marginedBottom}`}>
                <Box className={classes.dropZone}>
                  <FieldFileUploader
                    required
                    fileType="resumes"
                    fieldLabel="Click or Drag file here to upload resume"
                    accept={['application/pdf']}
                    name="resume"
                  />
                </Box>
              </Box>
              <Typography className={classes.formText} variant="h6">Check the box of the ones you don&apos;t have.</Typography>
              <Box className={classes.marginedBottom}>
                <FormGovernmentIds setData={setData} data={data} />
              </Box>
              <Typography className={classes.formText} variant="h6">Preliminary Questions</Typography>
              <Box className={`${classes.fieldContainer} ${classes.marginedBottom}`}>
                <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.textField}>
                  <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-age-native-simple">{variables.title}</InputLabel>
                  <Select
                    native
                    value={state.client}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    label="How did you hear about us?"
                    inputProps={{ name: 'client', id: 'outlined-age-native-simple' }}
                    onClick={
                      (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => setData({
                        ...data,
                        [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
                      })
                    }
                  >
                    <option aria-label="None" value="" />
                    {relationOptions.map((item, index) => (
                      <option key={index} value={item.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase()}>{item}</option>))}
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
              </Box>
              <FormRadioQuestions
                fieldClassName={classes.fieldContainer}
                textClassName={classes.textField}
                values={radioValues}
                setData={setData}
                data={data}
              />
              <Box className={classes.fieldContainer}>
                <FieldCheckbox className={classes.textField} name="confirm-registration" label={checkBoxLabel} />
              </Box>
              <Box className={classes.fieldContainer}>
                <Button component="button" type="submit" className={classes.spaced} variant="contained" color="primary">
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </Box>
            </form>
          )}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default PublicApplicationForm;
```

The **FormPersonalInfo** component consists of fields such as applicant-first-name, last name, email, location, mobile, etc.

When I click on the AddCircleIcon button to show some other fields and to add experiences/education, I got this error.
[image]

When I click the submit button I only got this log.

[image]

This is the Experience forms same with Education forms
[image]

My goal is to add experince and education array to the result set just like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, there are `<form>` tags nested.

**Quick example to reproduce error**

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {

return <form>
  <form></form>
</form>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

In your case `showExp` evaluates to `true` after click action, then `FormExperience` component, which apparently has `form` tag in it, renders and `validateDOMNesting` throws error.

```
  showExp && (
    <FormExperience
      onCancel={() => setOpenExp(false)}
      onSave={onAddExp}
      handleBlur={handleBlur}
    />)
```

Comment: Yeah, does it affect why I'm not getting the values from it?

Comment: I can't see any other culprit apart from that so yeah

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case before I managed to solve it using Material UI Portals

```
    import React from "react";
    import Portal from "@material-ui/core/Portal";

    export default NestedForms = () => {

      const container = React.useRef(null);

      return (
        <>
          <form>
              {/*form content  */}
              <div ref={container} />
              {/*form content  */}
          </form>

          <Portal container={container.current}>
              <form>
                      {/*  otherform */}
              <form/>
          </Portal>
        </>
      )
    }
```